# I have a redirect 301 after creating a new VM instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I have an E-commerce using Magento 1.9 located on Google Cloud Server. so, in order to create a new test enviremont .
I created a Snapshot for one of my VM instances. Then, I created a new VM Instances using the Snapshot taking from the first VM. So, now I have 2 VM with different IP address and same content. 
when I tested the IP from the new VM, I see that it redirect to the first VM. 
I check the .htaccess and I didn't see any redirect 301.
Anybody know what can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change the secure & unsecure base url in the database for that to happen.

1. Login to phpMyAdmin and open up the '`core_config_data`' table.
2. Look for records with '`web/secure/base_url`' and '`web/unsecure/base_url`'. There you need to change the value with the new IP address.

Hope this works for you.

KP

Comment: Hi K-P. thanks for your reply. I changed the secure and unsecure Base URL with the new IP address and didn't works.

Comment: HI, try to clear the cache and try that again. If not then me a message maybe I will help you out directly on teamviewer or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a snapshot of an Nginx instance and created several instances from that snapshot.
 I have tested all these new instances and I don’t get the redirect 301 error.

If a firewall in the new instance has no forwarding rule allowing this redirection to occur, I suspect that this is to do with an error that stems from the actual snapshot/new instance creation.

You could try creating another instance from the snapshot and trying again. If the issue happens again, then try creating another snapshot and new instance again from the new snapshot and proceed to connect to the new instance via its external IP address.

As I mentioned before, this behavior should not be happening. I suspect that the new instance was created and added to the same pool or cluster as the old instance. It appears that there is a connection problem to the new instance and the call gets redirected to the old instance which is in the same cluster/pool.